# Let $p$ be a prime number with $p \equiv 3 \pmod 4$. Prove that (${p-1} \over {2}$)! $ \equiv (-1)^{n} \pmod p$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Let $p$ be a prime number with $p \equiv 3 \pmod 4$. Prove that (${p-1} \over {2}$)! $ \equiv  (-1)^{n} \pmod p$, where n is the number of positive integers less than $p \over 2$ that are quadratic nonresidues of p.

Pretty sure this involves Wilson's theorem, but I don't have many other ideas. Especially the "number of positive integers less than $p \over 2$ that are quadratic nonresidues of p" part.

Answer (score 0):

By Wilson' s theorem 
$$\left[\frac{p-1}{2}!\right]^2\equiv 1 (\mod p)$$
Here the congruence $p\equiv 3\mod 4$ was used, but another consequence is that $-1$  is a quadratic non residue. Now for every $k$,
$$k\equiv x^2\mod p$$ or 
$$k\equiv -x^2\mod p$$ according as $k$ is or is not a quadratic residue, and where we can assume that $1\leq x\leq \frac{p-1}{2}$. Further as $k$ runs through this domain, $x$ also achieves each values once.
Thus we have that 
$$\frac{p-1}{2}!\equiv (-1)^n\left[\frac{p-1}{2}!\right]^2 \mod p$$