# Find $(1008)!\equiv ?\pmod {2017}$

Tags: number-theory

Find 
$$(1008)!\equiv ? \pmod {2017}$$

From the Wilson theorem I can $2016!\equiv -1\pmod{2017}$

Considering the general：
$$\left(\dfrac{p-1}{2}\right)!\equiv ?\pmod p$$
where $p$ is prime number

Comment: See [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2007031/let-p-be-a-prime-number-with-p-equiv-3-pmod-4-prove-that-p-1-over-2?rq=1), but with $p\equiv 1\bmod 4$.

Comment: How  to  Determine the number of positive integers less than $\frac{p}{2}$ that are quadratic nonresidues of p

Answer (score 8):

$(p-1)!=1\cdot2\cdots\frac{p-1}{2}\cdot\frac{p+1}{2}\cdots(p-2)(p-1)$ and $(p-1)!\equiv 1\cdot(-1)\cdot2\cdot(-2)\cdots\frac{p-1}{2}\cdot\left(-\frac{p-1}{2}\right)\pmod p.$

From Wilson's theorem, $(p-1)!\equiv -1\pmod{p}$

Implies $\left[\left(\frac{p-1}{2}\right)!\right]^{2}\equiv (-1)^{\frac{p+1}{2}}\pmod{p}$

Comment: How to Determine the number of positive integers less than $\dfrac{p}{2}$  that are quadratic nonresidues of p ,when $p=2017$

Comment: Since $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$, $a$ is quadratic non-residue iff so is $p-a$. Combine it with fact that there's equal amount of residues and non-residues from $1$ to $p-1$ to get the answer $504$.